# C# String.Trim() not removing characters from MailMessage.Subject

Tags: c#, trim, mailmessage

I'm trying to eliminate certain symbols from the `Subject` property of a MailMessage object. What I'm experiencing is that it does nothing. Even after assigning `Subject` to a string, and trimming that, the final `Subject` still has the symbols in it. *(not showed in example)*

```
MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage
{
    From = new MailAddress(mail.SenderEmailAddress),
    SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8,
    Subject = mail.Subject.Trim(new char[] {}), //symbol list, like ":", "~", ">"
    Body = mail.Body
};

String path = @"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\Documents\EML\";

if (!Directory.Exists(path))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
}

path = @"C:\Users\" + Environment.UserName + @"\Documents\EML\"
    + mailMessage.Subject + ".eml";

MessageBox.Show(path);
```

The message box is just to see whether the symbol gets removed or not at the moment, `path` will be put into a method later.

> mail has subject `RE: dog`, `.Trim` tries to remove `:`,
>
> MessageBox shows `C:\Users\user\Documents\EML\RE: dog.eml`.

Comment: You are referring to mailMessage.Subject.

Comment: Trim removes from the ends.

Comment: @john I tried with String.Replace() too, got nothing from that either.

Comment: Perhaps you could show the replace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MSDN:

> **String.Trim Method ()** - Removes all leading and trailing white-space characters from the current String object.

So, Trim isn't going to remove characters from the middle of a String.  Commenters suggested using Replace instead, but there isn't a signature that takes an array of characters like you are using.  An easy way around that is Extension methods.

```
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string text = "This:is~a>test";
            string subject = text.ReplaceFromCollection(new char[] { ':', '~', '>'}); //symbol list, like ":", "~", ">"

            Console.WriteLine($"{text}\n{subject}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }

    static class Extensions
    {
        public static String ReplaceFromCollection(this string text, IEnumerable<char> characters)
        {
            foreach (var chr in characters)
            {
                text = text.Replace(chr.ToString(), String.Empty);
            }
            return text;
        }
    }
```

Using this, each character in your string that matches a character in the array is replaced with the empty String one by one.  The result is then passed back.

[More reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) on Extension Methods.

Comment: This definitely worked, thanks. Will be reading more into that!

Comment: I'd highly encourage checking out Tommaso's answer below, which gets into some options I didn't cover for the character replacement method.  Any of them would work well in an extension method for String.

Answer (score 4):

The `String.Trim(Char[])` method, as per [official MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9(v=vs.110).aspx), removes all leading and trailing occurrences of a set of characters specified in an array from the current string object. If you want to remove all the occurrences of a specified list of characters from the string, even when they don't appear at the beginning or at the end of it, you may want to use a different approach.

Given the following example string and the following replacements:

```
String text = "This is: the~ mail sub~ject!";
Char[] replacements = new Char[] { ':', '~' };
```

you can perform this operation using various approaches. Here is a list containing a few of them:

**1) Using [String.Split](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx) and [String.Join](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0(v=vs.110).aspx)**

```
text = String.Join(String.Empty, text.Split(replacements));
```

**2) Using LINQ**

```
text = new String
(
    (from c in text
    where !replacements.Contains(c)
    select c).ToArray()
);
```

or:

```
text = new String(text.Where(c => !replacements.Contains(c)).ToArray());
```

**3) Using Regular Expressions**

```
text = Regex.Replace(text, "[:~]", String.Empty);
```

**4) Using a Loop and [String.Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1(v=vs.110).aspx)**

```
foreach (Char c in replacements)
    text = text.Replace(c.ToString(), String.Empty);
```

**5) Using an Extension Method**

```
public static String RemoveChars(this String input, params Char[] chars)
{
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (Int32 i = 0; i < input.Length; ++i)
    {
        if (!chars.Contains(input[i]))
            builder.Append(input[i]);
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}

text = text.RemoveChars(replacements);
```

The final output is always the same:

> This is the mail subject!